# Looking for the name of a particular subcategory of a comma category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Hi there. Suppose ${\bf C}_1$, ${\bf C}_2$ and $\bf D$ are categories and $F_i$ is a functor ${\bf C}_i \to \bf D$. Consider the subcategory of the comma category $( F_1 \downarrow F_2)$ whose objects are all triples $(c_1, c_2, e)$ where $c_i \in \mathrm{obj}(\mathbf C_i)$, $F_1(c_1) = F_2(c_2)$ and $e$ is the identity of $\hom_\mathbf{D}(c)$ with $c := F_i(c_i)$. Is there a standard name for this particular category? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (strict) pullback of $F_0$ and $F_1$.

Comment: Nothing more specific than this? Ok, I will wait to hear from somebody else, if any, before accepting your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrej: Great job!

Comment: I see, nothing but the (strict) pullback of $F_1$ and $F_2$. Ok!

Answer (score 3):

The (strict) pullback of $F_0$ and $F_1$.